# How to count the total number of things in Eclipse Ditto?

Tags: eclipse-ditto

I need to count the total number of things created in the Eclipse Ditto Digital Twin Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Ditto sandbox](https://ditto.eclipseprojects.io) you see that this information is displayed.

The API behind that is: `GET https://ditto.eclipseprojects.io/stats/search`.
Which basically does a "global count" on all things contained in Ditto's search index.